# Obtener el color de un texto en un div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo este `div` que genero dinamicamente con `javascript`.

```
<div class="texto-nombre-amigo" style="font-size: 14px; color:red">' + nombreAmigo[i].trim() + '</div>
```

> nombreAmigo[i]

es una array que pinta nombres de persona in distintos colores; red , blue... En el caso del ejemplo lo pinta en rojo con

```
 style="font-size: 14px; color:red"
```

Mi pregunta es:
¿Cómo puedo obtener el color del div, en este ejemplo `red` , desde jquery ?
Estoy intentando algo así

```
 var color = $(this).css('color');
console.log("color es=>"+color");
```

pero siempre obtengo el mismo resultado

> color es=> rgb(36, 37, 61)

Comment: `.css` te devuelve el código RGB del color. Si necesitas el nombre: `red, blue, green` ... tendrás que usar un plugin o manejar tu propio array con valores para poder extraer los nombres desde cada código RGB o usar algún plugin (no recomendado).

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que haces algo así: `let elInnerHTML = "<div class='texto-nombre-amigo' style='font-size: 14px; color:red'>" + nombreAmigo[i].trim() + "</div>"
elemento.innerHTML = elInnerHTML;` En este caso la única variable es el nombre del amigo, El color es rojo. Si el color es también una variable puedes utilizar el valor de la variable color. Por favor prueba mejorar tu pregunta para que podamos entender cómo generas el div dinamicamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haré un par de comentarios (aunque el resultado final si es un *tanto mas extenso*):

- No es una buena idea colocar estilos *inline* es decir dentro de la misma declaración de la etiqueta HTML
- El método CSS te devuelve como ya te dijeron el color en formato RGB
- Podemos auxiliarnos de JS para lograrlo, sin embargo considera lo siguiente:

  - Deberías declarar los estilos CSS entre etiquetas `style` o en una hoja por separado y asignarlos por medio de la clase que posee tu `div`
  - Nos podemos auxiliar de [**`getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) para obtener un objeto con todos los valores de las propiedades CSS
  - Posterior para acceder al valor CSS correspondiente usaremos [**`getPropertyValue`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) indicando como *string* la propiedad deseada
- Finalmente podemos con una estructura condicional verificar si el valor *rgb* es uno en específico y en concencuencia devolver el valor buscado, te puedes apoyar [de esta tabla de equivalencias](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/css/css-color.html#red)

Código:

```html
<style>
  .texto-nombre-amigo {
    color: red;
    font-size: 26px;
  }
</style>

<div class="texto-nombre-amigo">' + nombreAmigo[i].trim() + '</div>
<script>
let color = document.querySelector(".texto-nombre-amigo");
let colorLetra = getComputedStyle(color);
(colorLetra.getPropertyValue("color") === "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
 ? (console.log("red")) 
 : (console.log("Es otro color"))
</script>
```

Comment: En Javascript puro, se obtienen los colores por su nombre: `red, green, blue`, usando simplemente: `elElemento.style.color` mientras que `getComputedStyle()`, hace lo mismo que el método `.css` de jQuery, devuelve el color computado, o sea, el valor RGB del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

esto lo soluciona

```
var color = $('.texto-nombre-amigo')[0].style.color;
console.log("color es=>"+color);
```

Comment: Hola, aunque esta respuesta puede ser válida ya ayudar a solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una explicación de lo que hace o cómo funciona, se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] (con lo que ganarás tu primera medalla), y luego edita la respuesta para añadir algo más de información.